# Why my FFN does not converge to optimal value using L1loss while solving XOR problem?

Tags: python, math, pytorch

I tried to create the following FFN using *pytorch*:

```py
class BP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(BP, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2, 2, bias=True)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(2, 1, bias=False)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.sigmoid(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.sigmoid(self.fc2(x))
        return x
```

I used the following trainer to train this network:

```py
class Trainer():
    def __init__(self, model, loss, lr):
        self.model = model
        self.loss = loss
        self.lr = lr
        self.optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(self.model.parameters(), lr=self.lr)
    
    def train(self, x, y):
        self.model.train()
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        y_pred = self.model(x)
        loss = self.loss(y_pred, y)
        loss.backward()
        self.optimizer.step()
        return loss.item()
    
    def predict(self, x):
        self.model.eval()
        return (self.model(x) > 0.5).float()
```

My main program looks like this:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
    bp = BP().to(device)
    x = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]])
    x = torch.tensor(x, dtype=torch.float32).to(device)
    y = np.array([[0], [1], [1], [0]])
    y = torch.tensor(y, dtype=torch.float32).to(device)
    Losses = [1]
    trainer = Trainer(bp, nn.L1Loss(reduction="mean"), 0.6)
    begin = time.time()
    for epoch in range(100000):
        loss = trainer.train(x, y)

        if (epoch % 1000) == 0:
            print('Epoch: {}, Loss: {}'.format(epoch, loss))
            
            if abs(loss - Losses[-1]) < 0.000008:
                break
            Losses.append(loss)
    end = time.time()
    print('Total training time via GPU: {}s'.format(end - begin))
```

But when using L1Loss for training, this network never converges to optimal solution, but it always converges while using L2 loss.

Is there anything wrong with my code or is there a mathematical explanation that using L1 loss cannot train BP to solve XOR problem?